# 'Apps in Testing' throws JS error on clientContext - Cannot find current web URL

Tags: 2013, site-template, site-definition, apps-development

I have some JavaScript running on top of my Master Page. It works well except on one Site. When a 'Developer' Site collection is created, it adds 'Getting Started' and 'Apps in Testing' to the Home Page. I have discovered the 'Apps in Testing' breaks my code with this error:

> Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find current web URL information on the page.

Here is the code that 'Apps in Testing' breaks

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(setMenuOptions, "sp.js");

function setMenuOptions() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); //It errors on this line!
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    ......
}
```

If I remove the OOB list 'Apps in Testing', no error is thrown when declaring the `clientContext`. Is the Delay in Script loading broken?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution to this. Somehow, even though I'm using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(), it doesn't wait for sp.js so I had to wrap it in Document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(setMenuOptions, "sp.js");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an issue with `Minimal Download Strategy`.

Try this

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { });
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(setMenuOptions,"sp.js");

function setMenuOptions() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    ......
}
```

Comment: I have had many issues with MDS. Let me try

Comment: This works as well!

Comment: Cool. I would suggest you follow this. The first line will request to load those files, and second statement will wait till it gets loaded. `document.ready` is `window.load` and don't guarantee `sp.js` is loaded.

Comment: Yes, but document.ready works in 'Site Contents' (viewlsts.aspx), whereas this technique throws the same error for me

Answer (score 0):

As a part of the new Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) the `sp.js` library is not loaded until explicitly called in SharePoint 2013.

**Solution**

Prefer `SP.SOD.executeFunc` over `SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method since it supports the load on demand scripts:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { 
    setMenuOptions();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the necessary scripts like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

And you can put in `ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded`, instead of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { });
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(setMenuOptions); 
    function setMenuOptions() { 
        // run your stuff here 
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // other stuff...
    });
</script>
```